# app crash when enters foreground and gives -[UITextField _applicationResuming:] deallocated instance… error

Tags: iphone, crash

My app works very well on `iPad` device. But when press `HOME` and then enters the foreground it will randomly crash. The debug console shows that

```
[UITextField _applicationResuming:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x...
```

I have many `UITextField` object in the `ViewController` and don't know which one and what happens. I created all these `UITextField` objects dynamically (not use storyboards) and put them in one property named dict_edittext (retain as `NSMutableDictionary` ) of the `ViewController`. Can someone point me out how to solve the problem. I don't know what's going on these `UITextField` objects when app enters the foreground.

Comment: You have a `weak` property somewhere that should be `strong`.

Comment: check the solution of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479993/error-when-viewcontroller-is-implementing-uitextfielddelegate

Comment: I think it is due to using the objects which are deallocated. To find that , you should use "Instruments" to generate Crash Report to check against Zombies.

Comment: I found one link for you :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601406/ios-app-crashes-on-resuming.